# Bluehost site using Wordpress with Verge3D plugin - Error

Tags: php, wordpress

Lost on this one. Followed all the FAQ's on BlueHost's site along with numerous searches.

**Goal:**
Create a 3D scene in Blender, Use Verge3D App Manager, Upload Project to WordPress using the Verge 3D plug-in, Add it to my site being hosted on BlueHost. (Whew!).

**Error:**
"Error occured during upload: broken connection or maximum file size exceeded.
Please check your connection or server upload size limits."

**Where:**
Bluehost -> WordPress -> Verge3D Plug-In -> Upload

**File:**
Folder selected is a pre-made application from Verge3D, "jewelry_configurator" ~ 266M

**php.ini creation:**
Bluehost -> Advanced -> MultiPHO INI Editor...
Created .ini file.

**php.ini location:**
Bluehost -> Advanced -> File Manager -> (Settings, Web Root, Show Hidden Files)

**php.ini contents:**

```
allow_url_fopen = On      
allow_url_include = Off  
display_errors = Off  
enable_dl = Off  
file_uploads = On  
max_execution_time = 30  
max_input_time = 60  
max_input_vars = 1000  
memory_limit = 256M  
post_max_size = 720M  
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440  
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"  
upload_max_filesize = 720M  
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

Comment: did you check this https://www.soft8soft.com/docs/manual/en/introduction/Wordpress-Plugin.html#Installation

Comment: Yes, hense the updated .ini file. I'm using the most up-to-date Chrome and Wordpress version is 5.3.2

Comment: is the plugin activated in wordpress admin?

Comment: Yes, I was able to upload a small 5M folder so far.

Comment: 1. Did you try to upload the plugin VIA **File Manager**?
2. Also, change the following line on PHP.ini and try again
`max_execution_time = 180  
max_input_vars = 3000  
memory_limit = 512M`

For better solution contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conversation on Verge3D's board.
https://www.soft8soft.com/topic/wordpress-add-on-upload-error/

php.ini file:
Create using 'MultiPHP Manager'
Edit using 'MultiPHP INI Editor'
Location = Home Directory (Root)

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 3000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
upload_max_filesize = 512M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

FTP or SSH the files in:
1. public_html/wp-content/uploads/verge3d
2. rename the folder to a 3-digit number (ex. '600')

Shortcode:
[verge3d id="600"]